# django filter by ManyToManyField of other object

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

in my models there are two classes:

```
class PageCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(PageCategory, related_name='page_categories', null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to retrieve 
(a) one page to view, and 
(b) all other pages that belong to the same categories in which that page belongs to in order to list them, too.

This is what I am doing (which is wrong):

```
def pageView(request, page_slug):
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=unicode(page_slug))
    pages = Page.objects.filter(displayable=True, categories__in=page.categories).exclude(pk=page.id).order_by('-timestamp')
```

I always get a `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

How it should be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`page.categories` is a `ManyRelatedManager` and not a list of `categories` (which is required for `__in` check). So you need to specify `page.categories.all()` to `__in` filter.

Your query changes to :

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(displayable=True, 
        categories__in=page.categories.all()).
        exclude(pk=page.id).order_by('-timestamp')
```